# Ember - Issue with HTTP POST request

Tags: ember.js, mongoose, http-post

I have written a (very) simple RESTFul Web service to retrieve data from MongoDB using Node, Express and Mongoose.

On the server side, I have this code:

```
router.route('/products').post(function(req,res){
    var product = new Product(req.body);
    product.save(function(err){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Product Added'});
});
```

When I submit a request from my Ember client, the req.body contains something like the following:

```
{ attributes: 
   { category: 1,
     name: 'y',
     price: 1,
     active: false,
     notes: null } }
```

The attribute names are exactly the same as my mongoose schema. I get no error but the document created in MongoDB is empty (just get the _id and __v fields).

What am I doing wrong. Should I convert the req.body further into ???

Answer (score 0):

A couple things that will help debug:

1) From a quick glance (I haven't used mongoose before) it looks like call back function passed to save takes two arguments.

2) I don't know if your code got cut off, but the sample above was missing a matching `});`

3) I made the function short circuit itself on error, so you will not see 'Product added' unless that is truly the case.

Try these fixes.

```
router.route('/products').post(function(req,res){
    var product = new Product(req.body);
    product.save(function(err, product){
    if(err){
       return res.send(err);
    }
    return res.send({message:'Product Added'});
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks Oren. I did lose some of the code when I did the copy/paste. In any case, it does not make any difference :-(. JP

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to my lack of familiarity with Ember and Node+Express. The data received in the server is slightly different from what I had first indicated: (first line was missing)

```
{ product: 
   { attributes: 
      { category: ... } } }
```

On the server side I can access my data using `req.body.product.attributes` (instead of `req.body`):

```
router.route('/products').post(function(req,res){
    var product = new Product(req.body.product.attributes);
    product.save(function(err){
    if(err)
        res.send(err);
    res.send({message:'Product Added'});
});
```